# How get ChildNodes > ChildNodes (Children of Children )

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Only JS no Jquery.

How to get All ChildNodes of container and than for each of the children get there children?

I don't want to add ID to each Wrapper that is child of grid-row, I am trying to target with "this" or at this index. This script should be dynamic without specifying any ID.
I can't use classes to get all Wrappers as I need to trigger each wrapper separately and apply changes to it.

I want to get all grid-row children "Wrapper" widths and store in a array.

I am using ChildNodes as it is compatible with all browsers.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var rows =  container.childNodes;
var rowslenght =  container.childNodes.length;

var rowsArray = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < rowslenght ; i++) {
 if (gridrow[i].nodeType == 1){  // this is to no retrieve text

     // I got all the children of grid-row. How I get grid-row children. 
    // var rowsChildren = rows[i].getAttribute('id');

   // here goes other if to go through each "Wrapper" width and set width

    // console.log( rowsChildren);
     console.log( rows);

return rowsArray;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="grid-row">
         <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
    <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
   <div class="grid-row">
         <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what with: document.getElementsByClassName("Wrapper") ?

Comment: because that will give me all elements, and I can't trigger afterward exactly that wrapper that I have selected.

Comment: `var res = [...container.children].reduce((res, ch) => res.concat(...ch.children), [])` to get the grandchildren of `container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var rows =  container.childNodes;
    rows  = removeTextNode(rows); // remove Text Nodes; 

// Loop through .grid-row
forEach(rows, function(row){
     
     // Get wrappers and filter them
     var rowWrappers = row.childNodes;
         rowWrappers = removeTextNode(rowWrappers);      
     // Now loop over the wrapper, and modify 
     // the current function adds `Wrapper-blue` to the wrappers.
     forEach(rowWrappers, function(wrapper){
          console.log(wrapper);
          wrapper.classList += ' Wrapper-blue';
     });

});

// this helper function removes extra spaces/breaklines which are considered as Nodes 
function removeTextNode(nodes){
    return [].filter.call(nodes, function(o){
        return o.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE;
    });
}

// Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/
function forEach(array, callback, scope) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // the first argument is thisArg which is the context and can used as `this` in the callback
    callback.call(scope, array[i], i); // passes back stuff we need
  }
};
```

```css
.Wrapper-blue {
   background:#ddd;
   margin:5px;
   width:60px;
   height:60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="grid-row">
         <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
    <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
   <div class="grid-row">
         <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="Wrapper">
                <div class="block"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem with forEach is that it is 75% slower than for loop :)

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs, you can revert back to classic for loop in your version. I used it because it's cleaner and help you understand what goes on. :)

Comment: I posted on how I solved it. but i love the way you cleaned up the nodes with function. Why is there a [] before for each. I can understand how to convert this into for loop. not that good as you.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs because `Element.childNodes` return a NodeList which is not an actual array, and lacks forEach method from its prototype. But with `[].forEach()` I can pass the NodeList, and eventually iterate over the components.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs, see updated answer which uses the classic for loop in a  cleaner way, plus retains the speed.

Comment: Thank you Adam, I will run some test to see what loop is the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

`rows[i].childNodes` will give you the `Wrapper` elements inside each `grid-row`, but then you will have to loop through them, too.

Comment: And that what I did in the end but there one thing missing when i first created this question and that is that you need to do a if statement to remove all the empty text fields as childNodes gives you everything

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get the second loop right as in the first loop I got all the childNodes including the empty text fields. I needed first to run the the for statement and than only filter the ones that has nodeType == 1.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var rows =  container.childNodes;
var rowslenght =  container.childNodes.length;

var rowsArray = new Array();

// Get all  the grid-row and run through them
for (var a=0; a < rowslenght ; a++) {

// If it is a HTML element than go through
 if (gridrow[a].nodeType == 1){  

       var wpChildren = gridrow[a].childNodes;
       var wpChildrenleght = gridrow[a].childNodes.length;

      // Run through all the wrappers
       for (var b =0; b < wpChildrenleght; b++){

        // only get grid-wrapper html
         if (wpChildren[b].nodeType == 1){
              console.log(wpChildren[b]) // here is your specific div
           }
        }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as hard as you're making it; you don't have to do multiple loops.

The below is supported by all modern browsers, including IE 9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var rows = container.getElementsByClassName('grid-row');
// NOTE: this assumes that you only want to get wrappers which are children of grid-rows which are children of a container

var wrapperChildren = [];

rows.forEach(function(row) {
  var wrappers = row.getElementsByClassName('Wrapper');
  // per comments, adding child count
  row['data-child-count'] = wrappers.length;

  wrapperChildren.concat(wrappers);
});
```

It gets easier still if the wrappers are only inside grid-rows already (then you could just select all of them by class name). [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5y0yvs4/)

EDIT

Per the comment, you want to know how many children each row has, that's easy to add as a data attribute (or any other custom attribute) and then access it after this function has run.

Comment: it was very important to get each grid-row children as I need to know the count of how many each row has wrappers as based on the count I will execute a different function,

Comment: Updated with a mechanism for doing that.